# Ruby On Rails Guide section 4.2 Say Hello Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext

I'm on section 4.2 of the Rails Guide. I started the server in 4.1 then cancelled it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>`. 
It then says: "To create a new controller, you will need to run the "controller" generator and tell it you want a controller called "welcome" with an action called "index", just like this:"

To do so it says: `$ bin/rails generate controller welcome index`

I downloaded Sublime Text to do so but I don't know what to do from here...

Comment: Instructions that start with `$` usually mean to execute it in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your app folder
like `cd /your_project_folder`

and then

`bin/rails generate controller welcome index`

All these actions should be executed inside terminal

Comment: I couldn't open it using that

Answer (score 1):

You run that command from the command prompt on Windows or the Terminal on a Mac.

Comment: I'm a newbie by the way. When I enter "$ bin/rails generate controller welcome index" into command prompt, what do I do from there?

Comment: What's your OS? Just enter the parts after the `$`.